# Best/most elegant way to divide all of the rows in one pandas DataFrames by an equal-length row in another DataFrames?

Tags: pandas

I was just wondering whether anyone had a good way to divide a whole Pandas DataFrames (row-by-row) by another row in a different DataFrame.

Example: Say I had one DF that was this:
col1: 1 3 col1: 2 4

and another like this:
col1: 2 col2: 2

How could I easily arrive at this DF:
col1: 0.5 1.5 col2: 1 2

Thanks!

Comment: What was wrong with the way you are currently using?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Couple of quick suggestions:  Come up with an example thats a bit clearer - dividing a 2x2 df by a 2x1 df is a little ambiguous. Also, try with 2 different values in the second df - using 2 twice is abit confusing. Finally, consider putting your code example in Pytho9n code block to enhance readability.

Answer (score 0):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 3, 5], 'b': [2, 4, 6]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [2, 4], 'b': [5, 10]})

df1:
Out[7]: 
   a  b
0  1  2
1  3  4
2  5  6

df2:
   a   b
0  2   5
1  4  10
```

df3 = df1 divided by first row of df2:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame(df1.values / df2.loc[0].values, columns=df1.columns)
df3:
     a    b
0  0.5  0.4
1  1.5  0.8
2  2.5  1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [`div`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html), or `/`:

```
df1.div(df2.iloc[0])
# or
df1/df2.iloc[0]
```

Output:

```
     a    b
0  1.0  1.0
1  3.0  2.0
```

Used input:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 3], 'b': [2, 4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1], 'b': [2]})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1.groupby(df1.index).apply(lambda dd:dd.reset_index(drop=True)/df2).droplevel(1)

  col1  col2
0   0.5   1.0
1   1.5   2.0
```